# fatal: Needed a single revision

Tags: git

My repo has 3 commits. I want to squash to one.

I ran `git rebase -i HEAD~3` and got this error:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream HEAD~3
```

I was able to run `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and then `git push origin +master` and now I have 2 commits.

But why couldn't I do `git rebase -i HEAD~3`?

Comment: the number behind `~` is how many steps you want to go back. So if you have 3 commits you obvoiusly can go back 2 commits only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HEAD~3` is the grand-grand-parent of the current commit. But since there are only 3 commits, there is no grand-grand-parent (the first commit is the grand-parent of the current commit).

You can achieve the desired outcome by using [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) followed by [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit --amend
```

[`git reset --soft`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---soft) moves the `HEAD` to the provided commit but doesn't change the work tree and the index. The `HEAD` now points to the first commit but the working tree and the index (the staged files) are synchronized with the original `HEAD`; all the changes between the first commit and the third commit are now staged, waiting to be committed.

[`git commit --amend`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---amend) updates the current commit (it is the first commit after you run `git reset --soft HEAD~2`).

Comment: why did you change my command to reset? i dont want to go back I want to squash with my current changes

Comment: You want to go back and combine the changes introduced by the three commits into a single one. This is one way to do it. There are other ways too (one of them is the one you have tried but it doesn't work because `HEAD~3` doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.30.1 (Q1 2021), a "[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/df26861c564b96e88330bc22fa7410b5ead686d9/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> will give a more explicit error message (since `HEAD~3` does not exist in your case):

```
fatal: no such branch/commit 'HEAD~3'
```

See [commit ca5120c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca5120c339de883c3f22161316416c91655651ab) (01 Jan 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit df26861](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df26861c564b96e88330bc22fa7410b5ead686d9), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca5120c339de883c3f22161316416c91655651ab): verify commit parameter
>
> <sup>Reported-by: LeSeulArtichaut</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> If the user specifies a base commit to switch to, check if it actually references a commit right away to avoid getting confused later on when it turns out to be an invalid object.